# xpath - node not followed by text node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Using Xpath, I want to find em tags, followed directly by strong tags. I need to find this:

```
<em>X</em><strong>Y</strong> <foo> bar baz</foo>
```

but NOT this:

```
<em>X</em> <strong>Y</strong> <foo> bar baz</foo>
```

(The difference is the space before the "strong" element). How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to find em tags, followed directly by strong tags.

Some context would be useful here, but try:

```
//em[following-sibling::node()[1][self::strong]]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works very well. I was missing the `following-sibling::node()`,  `following-sibling::*` would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Select the first following node which is an element or a text, then verify it's the expected element:

```
//em[(following-sibling::*|following-sibling::text())[1][self::strong]]
```